# XPath: Get following-sibling based on text() only

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

Using relative `XPath` with `Selenium`, is there a way to get the text contents of `following-sibling`, using the text contents of both siblings as guidance?

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Looking for</td>
            <td class="text-right">This!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above example, I want to retreive the text snippet `This!` based on the text `Looking for`.

The path needs to be *relative* in the sense that these table cells can appear anywhere on the page. The above is a cut-out of the full web page. There can also be other things inserted before inside the same `<tr>` block.

I have tried this which seems to find the first cell:

`//text()[contains(.,'Looking for')]`

However, I'm struggling with how to proceed to get the text in the 2<sup>nd</sup> sibling.

My attempt has looked something like (incorrectly):

`//text()[contains(.,'Looking for')]/following-sibling::text()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it right, here you go, you just needed to show where exactly you want to look for. I hope this helps:

```
//td[text()="Looking for"]/following-sibling::td[text()="This!"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: @Winterflags and to you too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below to find the 2nd sibling:

```
//table[@class='table']/descendant::td[last()]
```

To find find 1st sibling, below can be used:

```
//table[@class='table']/descendant::td[last()-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
//td[contains(text(),'Looking for')]//following-sibling::td[contains(text(),'This!')]
```

For more reference on sibling and ancestors [click here](http://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)