# How to select td value when previous td contains specific text

Tags: html, xpath

I just wonder how to select string = "Last Minute" but only when previous `<td>` in this `<tr>` contains specific text, in this case "Offer". Is there someone who can help me?

```
<tr class="row m-0 mb-25">
    <td class="color_b1 font_10 d-inline-block col-12 text-uppercase">Offer</td>
    <td class="d-inline-block col-12">Last Minute</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: Get following-sibling based on text() only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744647/xpath-get-following-sibling-based-on-text-only)

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT

As pointed out in comments my original suggestion does not account for positioning of elements. Being you are dealing with siblings the solution offered by Amrendra Kumar is correct. It could also be accomplished with the XPath below.

`//td[text()='Offer']/following-sibling::td[1]`

#### Original Answer

**Will only check to ensure that parent node has a node with text `Offer` May be useful to another**

```
//td[text()="Last Minute" and ../td[text()='Offer']]
```

This finds the `td` with value `Last Minute` moves up to parent `tr` and then checks for a sibling `td` with text of `Offer`
using the sample you provided this works. I would suggest copying your html into an Xpath tester and test to ensure desired result is always achieved, but given the information this should solve your issue.

Comment: This will select siblings whatever the order.

Comment: it will fail if input like this: `<tr class="row m-0 mb-25">
    <td class="color_b1 font_10 d-inline-block col-12 text-uppercase">Offer</td>
    <td class="d-inline-block col-12">Last Minute</td>
    <td class="d-inline-block col-12">Last Minute</td>
</tr>`

Comment: I have now edited my answer to account for order of nodes. You were both correct my response did not account for the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with position and its `text()` like this to achieve desire output:

```
//td[text()="Last Minute" and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td[.='Offer']]]
```