# How to get the text content of html w/o Id or tagname?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I´m working on a chrome extension (Using Javascript) for personal use that scrapes some data and exports it to a csv file, right now I'm having problems extracting some text nodes because their selectors (chrome css selectors) change depending on how many labels with the same class but different content exist.

Here is an example of the Html:

```
<li class="sc-account-rows__row">
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__label">RTF</div> // Title Label
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container">
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__price">-$ 1.485</div> // Price Label <- How to get This?
</div>
</li>

<li class="sc-account-rows__row">
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__label">some text</div> // Another Label
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container">
<div class="sc-account-rows__row__price">-$ 2.418</div> // Another price which I don't need but has same class
</div>
</li>
```

In other words the selector for this particular label can be:

```
#root-app > div > div.sc-account-section > div.sc-account-section__container > div.sc-account-module > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.sc-account-rows__row__price--container > div
```

or

```
#root-app > div > div.sc-account-section > div.sc-account-section__container > div.sc-account-module > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(9) > div.sc-account-rows__row__price--container > div
```

As you can see there is no Id or Name assigned to this particular label, I was using (successfully) this piece of code when the selector was always the same. (Notice this is inside an iframe)

```
var RTF_fee = "#root-app > div > div.sc-account-section > div.sc-account-section__container > div.sc-account-module > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(4) > div.sc-account-rows__row__price--container > div";

    if (iframe_document.body.contains(iframe_document.querySelector(RTF_fee))) {
        RTF_value = iframe_document.querySelector(RTF_fee).textContent;
        console.log(RTF_value);
    }
    else {
        RTF_value = "0";
        console.log(RTF_value);
    }
```

So, the question is: How to get the text content in the price label if I don't have a unique selector/Id for it?

I guess I could work with the fact the the price label class is always "sc-account-rows__row__price" and the label text before the price is always "RTF" but I don't know how to code this or if there is a better alternative.

I apologize for my poor "programming" language, I´m just a casual programmer)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to get price if title is RFT. Am I correct?

Comment: There is something unique about it. Maybe its index in the list of things which are just like it? Maybe the text of something nearby? You can use XPath via [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), which opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @Bülent Akgül Yes something like that, if title label inside main container contains "RTF" then read the content inside the correspondent price label? - I wonder if that would work.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey the only thing I can think of is the index inside the selector. Or the label just before which always contains the text "RTF".

Comment: I'd look into something like the answers to [this question, "XPath: Get following-sibling based on text() only"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34744647/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are looking for.

```
let labels = document.querySelectorAll(".sc-account-rows__row__label");

[...labels].forEach(label => {
  if (label.innerText === "RTF") {
    let price = label.parentElement.querySelector(".sc-account-rows__row__price").innerText;
    console.log(price);
  }
})

Console: "-$ 1.485"
```

If you need to use extra labels besides RTF:

```
let words = ["RTF", "something", "else"];

// change if condition to
if (words.includes[label.innerText]) {...}
```

Comment: Indeed a very complete answer, it's working flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using XPath, an old standard for navigating through XML that also works with HTML. In this case, you're looking for a `div` with the class "sc-account-rows__row__price" that has another `div` with the class "sc-account-rows__row__label" nearby that has the text "RTF".

The XPath for the div is

```
//div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__label"][text()="RTF"]/following-sibling::div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container"]//div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__price"]
```

It's a bit complex because of the nested nature of the price--container/price `div`s.

To get the text, you'd use [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate):

```js
function getPriceByLabel(label) {
  // change this to a parent element if you can; it will speed up the process.
  const contextNode = document;
  const priceResults = document.evaluate(`//div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__label"][text()="${label}"]/following-sibling::div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container"]//div[@class="sc-account-rows__row__price"]`, contextNode, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
  const priceElement = priceResults.singleNodeValue;
  const price = priceElement.textContent;
  return price;
}
console.log(getPriceByLabel("RTF"));
console.log(getPriceByLabel("some text"));
```

```html
<li class="sc-account-rows__row">
  <div class="sc-account-rows__row__label">RTF</div>
  <div class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container">
    <div class="sc-account-rows__row__price">-$ 1.485</div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="sc-account-rows__row">
  <div class="sc-account-rows__row__label">some text</div>
  <div class="sc-account-rows__row__price--container">
    <div class="sc-account-rows__row__price">-$ 2.418</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I put it in a function that takes a label and spits out the price.

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about the XPath standards. I was checking on your previous answer about document.evaluate method, and you came up with an example. Brilliant! Thanks for your time.